# Fatal Error trying to use GuzzleHttp in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a POST request using Laravel 5.2 and GuzzleHttp Client. I've successfully installed GuzzleHttp with Laravel but it just keeps repeating an error.

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\API\Client()`

Here is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\APIConfiguration;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class APIController extends Controller {

  public function __construct(Request $request){
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function doShardDetails(Request $request) {
    $APIConfig = new APIConfiguration();
    $client = Client();
    $json = $APIConfig->jsonTemplate("Method");

    $request = $client->post("IP:PORT", $json);

    return $request;
  }

}
```

I've been trying to fix this for hours, nothing on the internet. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
$client = Client();
```

You should create a new object:

```
$client = new Client();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\API\Client()`

you need import `Client` class right way - with it own namespace, because namespace `App\Http\Controllers\API` do not have class name `Client`

Comment: So you're saying remove namespace and it'll remove the error?

Comment: no, i think fw do not figure out what is Client class, so it call Client from `App\Http\Controllers\API`, are you sure have GuzzleHttp\Client in autoload

Comment: Let me check autoload.

Comment: Okay so it's not in autoload, what do I have to put in autoload?

Comment: also, i don't see any properties call `request` are you missing something else

Comment: you can use composer to install dependencies

Comment: `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

Comment: try this  $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

Comment: In terminal composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle

Comment: @VeerendraBorra `Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\API\GuzzleHttp\Client' not found`

Comment: @swagster btw, did you install guzzlehttp from file or composer

Comment: I installed GuzzleHttp from composer

Comment: so you fixed this problem

Comment: No. I haven't fixed anything. I just keep getting errors.

Comment: try this `$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();`

Comment: i don't see any thing wrong with your import statement, maybe Client class is ambiguous

Comment: Okay so that finally worked, I'm just getting a cURL error. But it might have to do with my SSL `cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`